# Best way to handle horizontal scrolling to switch lists of data?

Tags: forms, mobile-application

So I'm creating a simple app to track bets with my friends. The pieces of information that are important to me are who they are (nickname), how much weight our bets are (virtual f.u. coins collected), and what the wager and terms are - wagers can be anything concrete such as bitcoins or made up such as "hugs", which will be whitelisted with an FU.coin weight (all made up mind you). I really just want single screen to all this on. So I thought what if I could swipe left or right to scroll through the list of options. If someone is not on my list such as a group of people or person - I can just click in the center of that input and add it, and then it would in turn be added to the horizontally scrolling input via swipes. Also, my send button looks horrendously large, with the twitter-like add new "bet" option next to it. So I beg thee -

- Am I just cramming too much info onto one screen?
- If so, should I transition each item on click per screen? For example, if I click on "who", it would load a new view with the hierarchical groups, or users I can select from (the idea is so that the users dont have to retype or search, just kinda click through stuff to find)
- If not - should I show the previews for prev/next you see next to each input or just < or > to help them know to scroll one way or the other?

Thanks for any input, I have zero ux/ui skills, just trying to do something simple.

[image: Prototype of Betting App]

Comment: I would take a step back for a minute. It would be worth doing a short task analysis exercise to better understand how it will be used and then design the application to fit that. https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/task-analysis.html

Comment: I would recommend also dropping back to paper. Put a few rectangles down on the paper and sketch up some concepts of how the app flows. Doing this will help you make it a reality much more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Each box in the flow below is probably a screen. Each line and diamond is some action. Dashed lines are likely disconnects between steps in the flow, but are there to illustrate order.

[image: A simple task flow for what I think your app is about.]

Comment: Thank you for all the information, I'm re-reading the links a bunch to fully grasp, and going over the exercise you wonderfully illustrated above to let it sink in. I will show what I have soon.